# Showing Multiple Noty Notifications With a Delay

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, notifications

I'm using [noty](http://needim.github.com/noty/) to display notifications using the 'top right' alerts setting. I'm really new to jquery but know php and mysql enough to get most things i want done.

What i want to do is use mySQL to get the data to see if a user needs to be shown any notifications (done). Then show that notification on page load, which I've also done, although I'm sure there's a more elegant way to show multiple notifications other than repeating the code?

Then i want to put a delay of say 1 second for each notification to appear so they don't all pop up at once, and disappear at the same time. I've looked into .delay() but without knowing jQuery a little better it's pretty useless to me.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var noty_id = noty({"text":"a message","layout":"topRight","type":"inormation","animateOpen":{"height":"toggle"},"animateClose":{"height":"toggle"},"speed":1000,"timeout":5000,"closeButton":false,"closeOnSelfClick":true,"closeOnSelfOver":false,"modal":false});
  var noty_id = noty({"text":"a message","layout":"topRight","type":"inormation","animateOpen":{"height":"toggle"},"animateClose":{"height":"toggle"},"speed":1000,"timeout":5000,"closeButton":false,"closeOnSelfClick":true,"closeOnSelfOver":false,"modal":false});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use the [`setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) native Javascript function. This will queue up an action after a given timeout period (*milliseconds*).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var noty_id = noty({"text":"a message","layout":"topRight","type":"inormation","animateOpen":{"height":"toggle"},"animateClose":{"height":"toggle"},"speed":1000,"timeout":5000,"closeButton":false,"closeOnSelfClick":true,"closeOnSelfOver":false,"modal":false});
    setTimeout(function() {   var noty_id = noty({"text":"a message","layout":"topRight","type":"inormation","animateOpen":{"height":"toggle"},"animateClose":{"height":"toggle"},"speed":1000,"timeout":5000,"closeButton":false,"closeOnSelfClick":true,"closeOnSelfOver":false,"modal":false}); }, 5000)
});
```

You may find [jQuery Pines](http://pinesframework.org/pnotify/) a better notification system for queuing up multiple notifications.

Comment: is there no function to just say like noty_id.show()